# Is it possible to emulate iOS on Android?

Tags: ios, emulators

Some apps are exclusively made for iPhones, thus I would like to know if there is a way to make iPhone apps work on Android. Emulator maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Some Columbia University students have managed to get iOS apps running on Android with their [Cider](http://systems.cs.columbia.edu/projects/cider/) compatibility layer. As far as I can tell this is not something that is available to the public but it shows that there is some development effort into getting iOS apps running on Android.

I wouldn't get too excited yet though as most iOS apps run very very slowly and they also don't have access to most hardware features such as GPS.

Comment: Again you beat me to it (+1). Maybe you want to include a [link to more details](http://www.engadget.com/2014/05/14/ios-apps-run-on-android/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these three emulators:

1. Appetize.io Online iOS Emulator
2. Corellium Online iOS Emulator
3. RunThatApp iOS Online Emulator

I'm not sure if anyone of them is paid or not.
**Source URL**: https://whofixit.com/3-best-ios-online-emulators-for-pc-android/